# Woocommerce Shipping label just hangs

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

When I got to Order->Edit Order->Shipping Label, the bar just spins and will not proceed to Verify Address, choose package, choose USPS Shipping Method, Buy Label.

Interestingly, if I reinstall Wordpress it will work for a short period of time.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!